# Getting JSON response from the server but can't display as HTML with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I'm building a mobile app and i build a PHP API that renders data from a mysql db and encode it as JSON

i call this api with Jquery ajax to get to display the records from the json output as JSONP and render it in my document in the success function.

so far i get the JSON correctly when i do the request via $.ajax and i can see the data in the Response in my firebug but in the other side the ajax function fires the ERROR not the Success.

i have a demo code in here :[jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/bassemclub/zatkg/)

this is my $.ajax Call:

```
$(document).on("pageinit","#myPage", function() {   
    $("#autocomplete").on("listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
            $ul.html( "" );            
            var dataString = 'keyword='+value;
        if (value.length > 2 ) {            
            $.mobile.loading("show");                       
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://example.com/search.php",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',               
                cache:true,             
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data) {               
                $.mobile.loading("hide");                                       
                alert(data);                     
                }
            })         
        }
    });
});
```

if you check the net panel you 'll find it successful and there is data coming.

Kindly Advise.
Thanks A lot

Comment: What am I supposed to type so that I don't get `No Results for :"bas"` returned and instead get this `JSON` object you speak of? Damnit, I'm not a wizard man!

Comment: try typing "oyo" or "above"

Answer (score 2):

Your response is not including the callback jsonpCallback() in the response, the response I'm seeing is simply 
`({"name": ... })`

Comment: i have the callback function now but when i get one set of JSON data its a valid JSON code but when the response comes with more than one record the JSON syntax becomes invalid. my PHP JSON ENCODE is like this :  'echo $_GET[$keyword] . '['.json_encode($row).']';' And this produces an invalid synatax when i get more than one value in the response like this 'Parse error on line 11:
...chord": "Am"    }][    {        "nam
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'